# Is returning 'None' for Python function ever a good idea?

Tags: python

The question is in the title...

I'm in a process of learning Python and I've heard a couple of times that function returning None is something you never should have in a real program (unless your function never returns anything). While I can't seem to find a situation when it is absolutely necessary, I wonder if it ever could be a good programming practice to do it. I.e., if your function returns integers (say, solutions to an equation), None would indicate that there is no answer to return. Or should it always be handled as an exception inside the function? Maybe there are some other examples when it is actually useful? Or should I *never* do it?

Comment: Example would be a function for finding the first item in a list that matches certain criteria, if the item is not found, returning `None` would be the best option IMO. Although you could also raise an exception, `None` seems pretty clear considering the situation

Comment: Disagree: a lookup that returns None is telling me that the object it found is the None object. Too iffy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This just flat-out isn't true. For one, any function that doesn't need to return a value will return `None`.

Beyond that, generally, keeping your output consistent makes things easier, but do what makes sense for the function. In some cases, returning `None` is logical.

If something goes wrong, yes, you should throw an exception as opposed to returning `None`.

Unfortunately, programming tends to be full of advice where things are over-generalized. It's easy to do, but Python is pretty good with this - *practicality beats purity* is part of the Zen of Python. It's essentially the use case for `dict.get()` - in general, it's better to throw the exception if a key isn't found, but in some specific cases, getting a default value back is more useful.

Comment: "unless your function never returns anything" - so I'm talking only about functions which you wouldn't call 'void'

Comment: @sashkello The rest of my answer addresses that.

Answer (score 0):

```
def abc():
 print 1
 return None
 print 2
```

is the same as

```
def abc():
 print 1
 return
 print 2
```

or even

```
def abc():
 print 1
```

All functions that don't return something return `None`. One very important use case of returning `None` is when you want to say "terminate this function" without having to nest a bunch of ifs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I feel like this refers to sort of breaking out of the function in case of error, isn't it?

Comment: @sashkello: Yep. What `return None` does can be covered with nesting ifs. However, `return None` is much cleaner. Similar to `return;`  in Java. (Or, in a way, to `die();` in PHP)

Answer (score -1):

It's a little complicated. 
It comes down to cases here:

A function that merely mutates its object's state doesn't return anything (returns None). For example, given a list called L: L.sort(); L.append("joe")

Other functions create a new object or a new copy of an object, and return it without mutating the original list. Consider: sorted(L) ; y =  L + [1,2,3]

It's generally bad form to return None meaning "everything is fine."

If you have some kind of lookup/accessor, None means "the value of that item is None", and when it's not found you should throw the appropriate exception.

In most other cases, returning None is a little confusing.