# When do you write function that doesn't return anything

Tags: python, return

I'm new to this, hope someone can help with my basic question to help clarify my concept.

I was playing around to shorten the code, but the 2nd case didn't work.

I think it didn't work because remove() doesn't return anything. Is that correct?

This got me wondering. When do you want write function that doesn't return anything? Isn't it always good to return something even though it might be get used? How do you work with function that doesn't return anything.

```
s = 'abc'

# This remove a from the abc
x = list(s)
x.remove('a')

# if remove() can return the list this would be simpler
x = list(s).remove('a')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is returning 'None' for Python function ever a good idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252331/is-returning-none-for-python-function-ever-a-good-idea)

Comment: I think you want 'pop()'

Comment: `sys.exit()` is a good example of a function that doesn't return.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75851273

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of style. I, and plenty of others, agree that in general it is much more useful to have a function return something - in particular, methods of an object which return `self` rather than `None` allow chaining.

Unfortunately, that's not what most people in the Python community do, and it's not what the creators of the built-in libraries do. You're going to have to learn to cope with this, and given that the style is pervasive, decide whether you want to cope with switching between styles, or conform to the dominant paradigm.

Comment: **Unfortunately** ?? Why Unfortunately ??

Comment: @eyquem I believe the first paragraph explains sufficiently. It's a more flexible style.

Comment: Most of the class methods in pyparsing return self. I picked this up from my Smalltalk years, where that is the typical idiom.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Yep, it's frustrating because Python is similar to smalltalk in a lot of respects.

Answer (score 4):

Many programmers are proponents of what is known as the [Command-query separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation). Functions that return values (*queries*) will in general not have side effects, while functions that have side effects are *commands* that in general won't return much interesting data. The separation has the intention of making it easier to keep track of changes in global state.

Answer (score 2):

A function always returns something: if there is no `return` excuted during the call of a function , `None` is returned.

It may happen that no `return` is excuted during a call,  when none of the conditions that lead to a `return` gives a True result, as in the following code:

```
def f(x):
    if x==2:
        return 'hello'

y = f('brouef')

print 'y ==',y
```

it prints

```
y == None
```

That also may happen if there is no `return` statement in the code block of the function, as in the following code.

.

That said, an algorithm doesn't always require to use returns of function. A function can transform something without to return anything else than a `None`.
For example:

```
li = [1000]

def f(x):
    for i in xrange(100):
        if i%3==0 and not i in range(20,85):
            li.append(i)

print li
f(li)
print li
```

result

```
[1000]
[1000, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 87, 90, 93, 96, 99]
```

That's the choice that was taken for `sort()`, for example, to make the coder well aware that the sorted object is changed in place. That is said in the doc.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense if the purpose of the function is to issue a side effect, like changing a global variable, performing input/output or call other functions with side effects. And in the end "no value" is a return value in itself, which is why e.g. functions in the C programming language are tagged with return type void.

Functional programming languages see side effects as a bad thing, and limit them.